# How to Send Bitcoin from one Wallet to Another Wallet in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, bitcoin

I am in the process of developing a custom Bitcoin wallet, I am able to generate the public/private keys by using Yenom/BitcoinKit. I need to send BTC to another wallet for which I am trying to use [BitcoinKit](https://github.com/yenom/BitcoinKit). But I could not send Btc. How do I do this? can we use another Library other than BitcoinKit to send Btc from one wallet to another Wallet ?

> So how do I transfer BTC from one wallet to another in Swift, please
>   advise.

Answer (score -1):

**Please check the following link**

https://github.com/yenom/BitcoinKit/blob/master/Examples/Wallet/Wallet/SendViewController.swift

There is a function called `sendToSomeAddress`

```
private func sendToSomeAddress(_ amount: Int64) {
        let toAddress: Address = try! AddressFactory.create("bchtest:qpytf7xczxf2mxa3gd6s30rthpts0tmtgyw8ud2sy3")
        let changeAddress: Address = try! AppController.shared.wallet!.changeAddress()

        var utxos: [UnspentTransaction] = []
        for p in payments {
            let value = p.amount
            let lockScript = Script.buildPublicKeyHashOut(pubKeyHash: p.to.data)
            let txHash = Data(p.txid.reversed())
            let txIndex = UInt32(p.index)
            print(p.txid.hex, txIndex, lockScript.hex, value)

            let unspentOutput = TransactionOutput(value: value, lockingScript: lockScript)
            let unspentOutpoint = TransactionOutPoint(hash: txHash, index: txIndex)
            let utxo = UnspentTransaction(output: unspentOutput, outpoint: unspentOutpoint)
            utxos.append(utxo)
        }

        let unsignedTx = createUnsignedTx(toAddress: toAddress, amount: amount, changeAddress: changeAddress, utxos: utxos)
        let signedTx = signTx(unsignedTx: unsignedTx, keys: usedKeys())

        peerGroup?.sendTransaction(transaction: signedTx)
    }
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Buddy @hardikdevios . I will check it and try to implement it . If this works for me i will accept your answer

Comment: Hello @Hardikdevios , it contains change address , can you tell me what is it for ? why we need change address ?